# How to filter records when filter is a comma separated list of comma separated values in Laravel query

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a table which has a column in it containing a string of comma separated values (skills_id).

e.g. 1,2,3,4

Being passed in as a filter is another set of value.

e.g. 4, 5

So in the example below, the query should return any records where any of the filter values are in the skills_id column.

declare @table table
(
rownum int,
skills_id varchar(250)
)

insert into @table values (1,'1, 2, 3,4')
insert into @table values (2,'1, 2, 4, 5')
insert into @table values (3,'1, 3, 4')
insert into @table values (4,'3, 4')
insert into @table values (5,'1, 2, 5, 4')
insert into @table values (6,'3, 4, 5')
insert into @table values (7,'5')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `REGEXP` like so:

```php
$search = preg_replace('/\s*, \s*/', '|', $request->skills_id);

YourModel::whereRaw("skills_id REGEXP '{$search}'")->get();
```

If the incoming values are 1,2,3,4 without any space after the commas then adjust the regex pattern to be: `'/\s*,\s*/'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$slills = $request->preferences;
        $jobs =  $jobs->orWhere(function($query) use($slills) {
            foreach($slills as $skill) {
                $query->orWhere('keyskills_id', 'like', "%$skill%");
            };
        });
```

it work fine!